# Can someone give me an overview of gradient descent?

Tags: algorithm

I was just wondering if this is the case? What's the intuitive definition?

Answer (score 3):

Gradient descent is a method for finding the minimum/maximum value of some multidimensional function.  To keep things simple, imagine looking for the peak of a hill.  In this scenario, we're looking for a maximum (altitude) in 3 dimensions (longitude, latitude, altitude).  The function is the surface of the hill, with two inputs (longitude, latitude) and one output (altitude).

If you had to use gradient descent, you'd do this:

1. Work out the slope in each direction at your current location
2. Move a small distance in the direction of the steepest positive incline
3. If reached convergence, then stop.  Else, go back to step 1.

Convergence means that the result is not going to change significantly if you continue.  The above instructions generalize to an arbitrary number of dimensions.

To implement gradient descent in any language, you set up a loop, and implement the step above.  It's really the same no matter language you use.  Here's a good video about gradient descent with some pseudocode (not that different to Python): http://youtu.be/5u4G23_OohI?t=26m34s.